# Read release version from package in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

I have file in my repository with release version number, this file is used across all releases. Creating new release requires commit with new version number. Can I configure azure pipelines to read this number from repository and embed in release name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use Powershell script to read the version number from the file, and then use [logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#release-commands) to update the release name for the running release:

`##vso[release.updatereleasename]my-new-release-name`

Comment: Thanks! It is sad that is not mentioned in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-manage-the-names-for-new-releases